# Interesting problem on series convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Problem no 1
Since  $f$ is uniformly continuous and $1/(n+1)$ is Cauchy so the sequence of partial sums is $f(1) - f(1/(n+1))$ 
is convergent so the series is convergent

Please check whether this approach works!!

Comment: You don't need uniform continuity, but your approach is correct. The series is telescoping as you noted. $1/(n+1)$ being convergent and $f$ being continuous implies $f(1/(n+1))$ is convergent.

Comment: And for the differentiable case, use Mean Value Theorem ...